# Reusable Tibco subprocesses

Tags: reusability, tibco, tibco-designer

If I have a sub-process that I'm using it in two Tibco projects, what will be the best way to reuse it?

Currently I'm copying the sub-process in both projects, but this leads to duplicated code, which is just hard to maintain.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alternatively, if you're using BusinessWorks 5, use DTLs (design time libraries) that you can share across projects. Every time you change the DTL you need to build the project library (.projlib) and refresh your project/import the .projlib in the project that refers to it.

A common example of why you want to use design-time libraries is when you want to share utility processes (e.g. logging, unique-id generation, etc).

Comment: Should the DTLs be included in EARs or should they be deployed separately? How? It seems that building an EAR did not included the DTL, even though I successfully included it and I can see the DTL resources in the project.

Answer (score 2):

Prepare a BW 6.x Shared module project and create sub-processes. Import this shared module project into the workspace where you want the sub-process reused.

Comment: I'm using BW5, so I accepted the other answer, but I also voted yours. Thanks!